# What is meant by "carbon space class"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, contemporary-english

I'm taking an online class from someone who has lots of typos in his course materials.  I found these sentences in the course materials:

> Finally, there is a "Current Events" discussion area to which I will post periodically. You should check it regularly and contribute to those discussions. I see those discussions as the types of things that we would chat about at the beginning of every carbon space class and like to bring it in here.

From the context, I think that by "carbon space class," maybe he means "traditional format class."  Is this a quirk of my instructor's?  Or is it a thing?  I couldn't find anything online about this.

Comment: Please cite the source. Include the broader context, and a link, if possible.

Comment: @Kris - I'm not sure what I would be able to add to the question in this case.  Perhaps you've never taken an online college course.  The instructor's course materials are published in Blackboard for enrolled students only.  Unless you are enrolled in the class, you don't have access to them. And nothing would be gained by mentioning the instructor's name.

Answer (score 2):

Your instructor is using "carbon space class" to mean an in-person class session, where instead of meeting in *cyberspace* (the internet), you would be a bunch of [carbon-based lifeforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon-based_life) meeting in person.

I have never heard this term before, but it is very similar to [**meatspace**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/what-is-meatspace) and somewhat reminiscent of [**bricks and mortar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_and_mortar).

Comment: Thanks.  So it really is just him?  I can't find anyone else using the term "carbon space" as an alternative to cyberspace.

Comment: If *carbon space* is in wider use, I have not encountered it. Perhaps he thought it would be in better taste than *meatspace*.